# How to generate new variable from stored results: r(mean)?

Tags: special-characters, stata

I am trying to generate a new variable using the stored result `r(mean)` from the command `sum`.

I have a continuous variable 'age'.
So, 

`sum age
g age0=age–r(mean)`

The problem is that this gives the error 

`unknown function age–r()
r(133);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. su mpg

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |         74     21.2973    5.785503         12         41

. gen mpg0 = mpg - r(mean)

. su mpg0

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
        mpg0 |         74   -4.03e-08    5.785503  -9.297297    19.7027
```

Watch for strange characters, i.e. that the minus sign really is a hyphen [sic].

Comment: Unbelievable. You are right. I believe I must have copied the expression initially from somewhere else and put it into my do file.

Taking out that character and replacing it with my own typed in 'minus' character solved this.

Thanks and apologies for the silly mistake.

Comment:  done. But i think i have less than a certain amount of reputation so it does not reflect on that upvote arrow at the moment.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. Thnx.